# ASP.NET *.resx serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, internationalization, resx

I'm contributing on an I18N project and there's a call to serialize our *.resx files as JSON objects (for whatever reason).

What I'm wondering is:

- Is there a way to get a list of all of the valid keys for a given *.resx file so that we could use HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject to grab the tokens?
- If that won't work, has anyone come up with a clever solution that does?

Comment: One reason, if you are creating an app that relies on JSON data and AJAX calls, you may have to generate localized html snippets in Javascript without the aid of your C# View files.  In this case the JSON object with the resx data is invaluble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  Sub ReadRessourceFile()
       ''#Requires Assembly System.Windows.Forms 
        Dim rsxr As System.Resources.ResXResourceReader = New System.Resources.ResXResourceReader("items.resx")

        ''# Iterate through the resources and display the contents to the console.    
        Dim d As System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
        For Each d In rsxr
            Console.WriteLine(d.Key.ToString() + ":" + ControlChars.Tab + d.Value.ToString())
        Next d

        ''#Close the reader. 
        rsxr.Close()
    End Sub
```

Then you need to add this to a Serializable Dictionary, which you can then serialize to JSON using System.Web.Extensions.dll

```
Public Class JSONHelper

Public Shared Function Serialize(Of T)(ByVal obj As T) As String
    Dim JSONserializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()  
    Return JSONserializer.Serialize(obj)
End Function

Public Shared Function Deserialize(Of T)(ByVal json As String) As T
    Dim obj As T = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()
    Dim JSONserializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    obj = JSONserializer.Deserialize(Of T)(json)
    Return obj
End Function

End Class
```

Edit: C# :

```
public void ReadRessourceFile()
{
    //Requires Assembly System.Windows.Forms '
    System.Resources.ResXResourceReader rsxr = new System.Resources.ResXResourceReader("items.resx");

    // Iterate through the resources and display the contents to the console. '    
    System.Collections.DictionaryEntry d = default(System.Collections.DictionaryEntry);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry d_loopVariable in rsxr) {
        d = d_loopVariable;
        Console.WriteLine(d.Key.ToString() + ":" + ControlChars.Tab + d.Value.ToString());
    }

    //Close the reader. '
    rsxr.Close();
}
```

And the JSON helper:

```
public class JSONHelper
{

    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer JSONserializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        return JSONserializer.Serialize(obj);
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer JSONserializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        obj = JSONserializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Also, if you want to get the comment as well, you can set UseResXDataNodes to true. 
Example:

```
public static string ReadRessourceFile()
{
    string[] languages = new string[] { "de", "fr", "it", "en" };
    string pathPattern = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    pathPattern = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathPattern, "..", "..", "..", "libQrCodeGenerator", "Resources", "QRBillText-{0}.resx");
    pathPattern = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(pathPattern);

    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>> dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>(System.StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    foreach (string lang in languages)
    {
        dict[lang] = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>(System.StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        string file = string.Format(pathPattern, lang);
        System.Resources.ResXResourceReader rr = new System.Resources.ResXResourceReader(file);
        rr.UseResXDataNodes = true;

        // '# Iterate through the resources and display the contents to the console. 
        foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry d in rr)
        {
            System.Resources.ResXDataNode node = (System.Resources.ResXDataNode)d.Value;
            string value = (string) node.GetValue((System.ComponentModel.Design.ITypeResolutionService)null);
            string comment = node.Comment;

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comment))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(comment);
            }

            // dict[lang][d.Key.ToString()] = d.Value.ToString(); // when not using UseResXDataNodes = true
            dict[lang][d.Key.ToString()] = value;
        }

        // '#Close the reader. 
        rr.Close();
    }

    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: JFYI, most of SO users understands C# much better

Comment: Yep, the "secret" is using the built in ResXResourceReader class.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  This is going straight into my ApiController to be cached on the client-side javascript via Ajax call.  I'll have to modify it to store multilingual in the same JSON object.